# running appium against an already booted emulator

Tags: appium

I have got my appium tests running, however I am suffering about 50% test failures because of the amount of time it takes the app to install so appium is failing the tests.

Is there a way of getting appium to run against an already running device emulator which has the app installed and running or does it have to load the app itself every time?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely connect to the running emulator, you need to pass `udid`as capability. It works both for Android and iOS.

For Android use `adb devices` to get the value, for iOS - `instruments -s devices`. But if you connect only 1 device/emulator, you can ignore it.

To save installation time aka install only once, you can check [reset strategies](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/) and find what works for you:

e.g. for Android adding capability `noReset: true` will leave app as is on device after session is closed. When you start the 2nd Appium session, it will skip cleanup and simply open the app. Note: app cache won't be cleaned and may affect the test.